# Transfer an image into next activity in small size

Tags: java, android

06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:234)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at java.io.File.init(File.java:201)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at java.io.File.(File.java:152)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at com.example.newprojimage.upload.onCreate(upload.java:18)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-15 17:18:33.744: E/AndroidRuntime(402):  ... 11 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different questions in one eh, you can send the `selectedImageURI` to the next activity via an `Intent`;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("selected image",selectedImageURI);  
startActivity(intent);
```

Add that to your `onActivityResult` and then resize the image there.

In the next activity, probably in `onCreate`, resize image acc to what you need. Doing that would be a combination of:

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(new File(getIntent().getExtras().getString("selected image")));
yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

and need to understand a bit of re-sizing the image, as you have a few options depending on how it changes the quality of image, , how will it affect memory consumption etc so:
[Resize image bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381780/is-there-possibility-to-resize-the-image-programmatic-by-click-on-button)
or
[Shrink/scale bitmap](http://blog.mxtracks.de/en/2012/02/scale-images-in-android-with-bitmapfactory/)

Here's another [tutorial to resize a bitmap](http://android.okhelp.cz/resize-a-bitmap-image-android-example/)

Comment: what do you mean by show me error? if not calling it in oncreate, try Activity.this.getIntent...

Comment: @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activityfcy_main);
       ImageView imgv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
         Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(new File(this.getIntent.getExtras.getString("selected image")));
         imgv1.setImageBitmap(bitmap); I do like this

Comment: Take string separately from getintent and check if it is being passed correctly, and that its not null. What is the error that you get...check logcat man

Comment: check edit, missing the brackets in getIntent() and getExtras(), please read more about android development also, you'l then avoid [such questions also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012412/select-image-from-phone-gallery)

Comment: good it helped you, welcome, can try various tutorials available online and read as much as possible from [Android Developer Official - Section: Develop](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html)

Comment: Can ask a new question actually as you figured the first part out, now its a different problem :)